# Disable jquery ui sorting for last row of table

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable

How can I disable the drag and drop sorting for only last row of a dynamically generated table in angularjs using ng-repeat ? I am using jquery ui sortable. I want that the position of last row should be fixed at last position only. Also, the table rows are dynamically growing when user add rows while adding content to table. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Add some codes please. What have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't an issue for how you handle styling, than I would probably use a tfoot tag. You may be able to do this more elegantly using the angular $last command, but I can't think of how off the top of my head.

In your ngRepeat, specify that you want it to do `object in objects | notLast` where `notLast` is a custom filter that slices the array to all but the last element. Use that ngRepeat for the body. Now for the table footer, do `object in objects | last` with `last` being a filter that returns only the last element (could also be done with limitTo filter). Now just apply the JQuery sortable only to the body of the table.

This could also be done with ngIf and $last, but that seems like it would be messier.